# Import an osm file into matlab

Tags: matlab, openstreetmap

I want to import osm file into matlab. For that purpose I read the 
OpenStreetMap Functions by Ioannis Filippidis.

I started with `usage_example` but the follwoing error comes

```
usage_example 
Undefined function 'xml2struct_fex28518' for input arguments 
of type 'char'.

Error in load_osm_xml (line 27) 
map_osm = xml2struct_fex28518(filename); % downloaded osm 
file

Error in parse_openstreetmap (line 36) 
map_osm = load_osm_xml(openstreetmap_filename);

Error in usage_example (line 28) 
[parsed_osm, osm_xml] = 
parse_openstreetmap(openstreetmap_filename);
```

Then I read the various comments from that page and google, then I tried the following

1)I extracted the smaller map file from www.openstreetmap.org , even the error is same.

2) changed the path, even the error appears.

Kindly suggest and help me plz.

Comment: Did you try to contact Ioannis Filippidis?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you got indicates you are missing a file, specifically `xml2struct_fex28518`.

Some digging on the project's GitHub in the [history](https://github.com/johnyf/openstreetmap/commit/b02f80cae0d73f09c2450b7858702df91fb47e75) of the function throwing the error (`load_osm_xml`), shows that the missing function was renamed from `xml2struct` to avoid a conflict with another, official, toolbox.

Said digging also revealed the existence and requirement of a set of dependencies, which may be found on the project's [releases page](https://github.com/johnyf/openstreetmap/releases).

Go grab the `dependencies.tar` file, unpack it and add it to you MatLab path and it should work fine.

Comment: @Ioannis Filippidis might be worth considering a package/namespace approach instead of having to rename functions like this!

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou: I totally agree that namespaces are a good approach to this type of problem. As [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) puts it "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!". In the past few years, I've been working with Python, and haven't used MATLAB. One of the main reasons that this situation arises is the lack of organization analogous to PyPI (may be wrong if things have evolved since). This problem would be equivalent to a new standard library module named after an existing one on PyPI, instead of using a namespace `bioinformatics`.

Comment: This is partly true, but at the same time "Packages" (not to be confused with "toolboxes") are [a lot more low-level in matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html), so things are a lot simpler in this case. If you have a function defined in a folder like this: `/root/+MyPackage/myfunction.m` then you can call the function from /root like so: `MyPackage.myfunction()`. All I'm suggesting is rather than rename xml2struct to xml2struct_blabla, you could simply be putting it in a `+OSM` folder instead, and call it as `OSM.xml2struct` in the code.

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou Indeed, the ideal solution would be for the original author of the project to update their code to use packages.   That said, as a thing the OP can do, arbitrarily putting other peoples' code into a package folder isn't such a good idea, as [even local references must use the package name](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html), so there some refactoring would be required.

Comment: well, yes, agreed, though it could be as simple as adding an `import` statement to each packaged function.